# Random variables converging to a density in mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Important edit: this question has been moved to [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336719/dependent-random-variables-converging-to-a-density-in-mean).

Let $X$ be an absolutely continuous r.v. with density $f$ which is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. Consider some a.s. decreasing sequence $Y_n$ bounded by $X$ such that $Y_n\searrow 0$ a.s. I stress that all variables are **dependent** (in a complicated way).

**The question.** 
I would like to know if the sequence $1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}}/Y_n$ converges in mean to $f(x)$ (i.e., $\mathbb{E}(1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}}/Y_n)\to f(x)$) under mild conditions (e.g. $\mathbb{E}(1/Y_n)<\infty$ for all $n$ or $X$ having bounded support).

**Special cases.** The following examples are *not* what I am after, but I include them to provide some intuition and perhaps clarity.

1. *The independent case.* (Edit: new version due to [pre-kidney](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/34662/pre-kidney).)
   When $X$ and $Y_n$ are independent for each $n$, this is trivial. Indeed, the function $g_x:y\mapsto\mathbb{P}(x<X<x+y)/y$ is bounded and continuous on $[0,\infty)$ if we set $g_x(0)=g_x(0+)=f(x)$. Hence
   $$\mathbb{E}(1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}}/Y_n)= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}}/Y_n|Y_n))= \mathbb{E}(g_x(Y_n))\to f(x)$$
   by the dominated convergence theorem (as $g_x(Y_n)\to f(x)$ a.s.).
2. *The quotient can be sandwiched.* Assume that some random variables $0<L_n$ and $U_n<1$ are independent of $X$ and satisfy $L_n\leq Y_n/X\leq U_n$ for all sufficiently large (deterministic) $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $U_n/L_n\overset{L^1}{\to} 1$. In this case, we clearly have $U_n,L_n\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\to}0$ and, for sufficiently large $n$
   $$1_{\{x<X\leq x/(1-L_n)\}}/(U_nX)\leq 
   1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}}/Y_n\leq 
   1_{\{x<X\leq x/(1-U_n)\}}/(L_nX).$$
   Moreover, we may bound
   $$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1_{\{x<X\leq x/(1-L_n)\}}}{U_nX}\Big|U_n,L_n\right)
   \geq \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1_{\{x<X\leq x/(1-L_n)\}}}{U_nx/(1-L_n)}\Big|U_n,L_n\right)
   =g_x\left(\frac{xL_n}{1-L_n}\right)\frac{L_n}{U_n}.$$
   Since convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence in distribution, the continuous mapping theorem and the boundedness of $g_x$ imply that the last quantity converges in $L^1$ to $g_x(0)=f(x)$. Similarly, we bound
   $$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1_{\{x<X\leq x/(1-U_n)\}}}{L_nX}\Big|U_n,L_n\right)
   \leq \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1_{\{x<X\leq x/(1-U_n)\}}}{L_nx}\Big|U_n,L_n\right)
   =g_x\left(\frac{xU_n}{1-U_n}\right)\frac{U_n}{L_n}.$$
   which again converges in $L^1$ to $g_x(0)=f(x)$. By sandwiching, we conclude that $\mathbb{E}(1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}}/Y_n)\to g_x(0)=f(x)$.

**Flexibility of the result.**
It is not *necessary* that this exact result holds (for me). For instance, it would help if we have sufficient (and mild) conditions for: 
(I) $\mathbb{E}(1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}})/\mathbb{E}(Y_n)\to f(x)$ or 
(II) $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}}|X)/\mathbb{E}(Y_n|X)]\to f(x)$ or something similar. If you have such a result, a reference would be much appreciated. Counterexamples are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For $y>0$, let $g(x,y)=y^{-1}\mathbb P(x< X\leq x+y)$. By definition of the density, our hypotheses imply that $\lim_{y\to 0^+}g(x,y)=f(x)$.

Observe that (EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, this step actually is using independence of $X$ and $Y_n$) $\mathbb E(Y_n^{-1}1_{\{x< X\leq x+Y_n\}}\mid Y_n)=g(x,Y_n)$ a.s., and thus by continuity of $g$ and the fact that $Y_n\to 0$ a.s., it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(x,Y_n)=f(x)$ a.s.. Finally, we may remove the conditioning to obtain that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E(Y_n^{-1}1_{\{x< X\leq x+Y_n\}})=\mathbb E\lim_{n\to\infty} g(x,Y_n)=\mathbb Ef(x)=f(x).
$$

Comment: I agree that this is a better way of solving the case where $X$ and $Y_n$ are independent for every $n$, but the general case seems not to follow from this.

Comment: Why do you think this uses independence of $X$ and $Y_n$? It is just the tower property of conditional expectation, no?

Comment: $\mathbb E(Y_n^{-1}1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}})=\mathbb E[\mathbb E(Y_n^{-1}1_{\{x<X\leq x+Y_n\}}\mid Y_n)]$ in general

Comment: If you take $Y_n=X/n$, say, then $\mathbb{E}(Y_n^{-1}1_{\{x<X<x+Y_n\}}|Y_n)= \mathbb{E}((n/X)1_{\{x<X<x\frac{n}{n-1}\}}|X)=(n/X)1_{\{x<X<x\frac{n}{n-1}\}}$ which is not equal to $g(x,X/n)$. However, $g(x,x/(n-1))=\mathbb{E}(1_{\{x<X<x\frac{n}{n-1}\}})((n-1)/x)\leq\mathbb{E}((n/X)1_{\{x<X<x\frac{n}{n-1}\}})$ and $\mathbb{E}((n/X)1_{\{x<X<x\frac{n}{n-1}\}})\leq \mathbb{E}(1_{\{x<X<x\frac{n}{n-1}\}})(n/x)=g(x,x/(n-1))\frac{n}{n-1}$ so you can still get the convergence, by sandwiching.

Comment: Fair point - thank you for the correction, I have edited my answer as well.